# Odoo v11: ¿Como hacer que un campo sea dependiente del valor de otro campo dinámicamente?

Tags: python, odoo

Se poseen tres módulos:

```
class Modulo_A(models.Model):
    _name = 'modulo.a'
    name = fields.Char(description="Nombre A:")

class Modulo_B(models.Model):
    _name = 'modulo.b'
    name = fields.Char(description="Nombre B:")
    campo_a_ids = fields.Many2many('modulo.a')

class Modulo_C(models.Model):
    _name = 'modulo.c'
    name = fields.Char(description="Nombre C:")
    campo_a_ids = fields.Many2many('modulo.a')
    campo_b_id = fields.Many2one('modulo.b')
```

Se desea que en la vista form del Modulo_C al escojer el campo_b_id se filtre el campo_a_ids, es decir aparezcan solo los ids contenidos en el Modulo_b correspondiente.

Comment: Creo que deberías de hacer una consulta cada vez que cambie el valor en el campo_b_id, para esto te recomendaría que utilices la función onchange y agregues el decorador @depends con el campo que necesitas, después haces una consulta y haces el filtro, actualizando los campos del valor que requieres. Ahora, eso si es en la misma vista, de otra manera no funciona asi.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia el problema de hacerlo así es que el domain solo se cambia cuando el campo cambia. Me explico mejor: supongamos que se llenan los campos campo_b_id esto cambia el domain del campo_a_id al hacerlo por el metodo on change. Pero si luego se edita el mismo record y primero se escoja el campo_a_id que depende de b aparecen todos los registros sin filtro, y esto es obvio ya que el campo_b_id no ha cambiado. Alguna idea para que el dominio quede seteado en el campo_a_id cuando el campo_b_id no ha cambiado

Comment: saludos te sugiero revisar: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/when-changing-the-value-of-this-combobox-the-data-will-show-the-other-combobox-in-openerp-37128

Answer (score 1):

Después de 5 meses de investigar, se resolvió este reto a continuación la explicación para la versión 10 y 11 de Odoo:

1.- A partir de la versión 10 Odoo no permite ejecutar código desde los archivos xml con la función eval, por lo que no es posible guardar los campos dinámicos en un campo tipo chart como se lo hacía en la versión 9, por lo que es necesario guardarlos en un campo many2many computado, del cual dependerá el campo que queramos que tenga el dominio dinámico.

1-a.- Archivo Python.

```
class Modulo_C(models.Model):
    _name = 'modulo.c'
    name = fields.Char(description="Nombre C:")
    campo_a_ids = fields.Many2many('modulo.a')

    # Campo auxiliar que guardara los id del domain dinámico
    campo_a_domain_ids = fields.Many2many(
        string="Domain del campo a",
        comodel_name="modulo.a",
        relation="modulo_c_to_modulo_a_domain",
        column1="modulo_c_id",
        column2="modulo_a_id",
        store=True,
        compute=lambda self: self._compute_campo_a_domain(),
    )
    campo_b_id = fields.Many2one('modulo.b')

    # Método del campo cumputado many2many
    @api.multi
    @api.depends("campo_b_id.campo_a_ids")
    def _compute_campo_a_domain(self):
        for rec in self:
            campo_a_list = []
            camp_a_ids = rec.campo_b_id.campo_a_ids
            campo_a_list = [x.id for x in camp_a_ids]
            rec.campo_a_domain_ids = [(6, 0, campo_a_list)]

    # El dominio debe cambiar si el campo b cambia así que
    # es necesario cambiar el método onchange
    @api.multi
    @api.onchange("campo_b_id")
    def _onchange_campo_b_id(self):
        # Obtenemos los ids del modulo a guardados en el b
        modulo_a_ids = self.campo_b_id.campo_a_ids.ids
        # Borramos de la vista los ids antiguos
        self.campo_a_ids = [(5, 0, 0)]
        # Insertamos el dominio dinamico nuevo
        vals['domain'] = {
        "campo_a_ids": [("id", "in", modulo_a_ids)],
        }
        # guardamos los ids del nuevo domain en el campo auxiliar
        self.campo_a_domain_ids = [(6, 0, modulo_a_ids)]
        return vals
```

1-b.- Archivo xml.- Conectamos el campo dependiente (este caso el campo_a_ids) con el campo auxiliar para que su domain dependa de este(campo_a_domain_ids), no olvidar que en campo_a_domain_ids guarda los ids de los campo_a_ids guardados en el campo_b_id; Por lo tanto campo_a_ids termina dependiendo de campo_b_id, y cambia dinámicamente si campo_b_id cambia.

```xml
<field name="campo_a_domain_ids" invisible="1"/>
<field name="campo_a_ids" domain="[('id','in',eva_criteria_domain_ids)]"/>
```

Si te sirvió no te olvides de darle botón arriba